# Deep Reflection in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to create the ability to drill through an objects properties like two or three deep.   For instance, class A has a property reference to class B, which I need to access class C.  What is the best way to do this: straight reflection, or maybe using the TypeDescriptor, or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we get any more details? Any sort of usage or sample code? I've done all sorts of things with Reflection, and I'm still not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Simon yes, its public.  @drachenstern I'm basically trying to do what @Simon is doing in his post.

Comment: I'm creating a process for serializing deep objects, but in a special way to meet a specific need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too hard to write. I put a few classes together to deal with this so I could serialize properties of a WinForm. Take a look at this class and the related classes.

http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Reflection/PropertySerializer.cs

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path in a static context (ie the path is always the same) and the properties are accessible (internal or public) you can use dynamic

```
    [Test]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var a = new A
        {
            B = new B
            {
                C = new C
                {
                    Name = "hello"
                }
            }
        };


        DoReflection(a);
    }

    private void DoReflection(dynamic value)
    {
        string message = value.B.C.Name;
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

Comment: I'm creating a centralized process, so I need to be able to do it without knowing what the properties are.  That's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I you wanna write you own serialization code for whatever reason, you'll be using reflection.

What you do is that you write a recursive method of serlizating a type. You then apply this as you see fit to get the result.

```
var type = myObjectOfSomeType.GetType();
// now depending on what you want to store
// I'll save all public properties
var properties = type.GetProperties(); // get all public properties
foreach(var p in properties)
{
    var value = p.GetValue(myObjectOfSomeType, null);
    Writevalue(p.Name, value);
}
```

The implementation of `WriteValue` have to recognize the built in types and treat them accordingly, that's typical things like string, char, integer, double, DateTime etc.

- If it encounters a sequence or collection you need to write out many values.
- If it encounters a non trivial type you'll apply this recursive pattern again.

The end result is a recursive algorithm that traverses your object model and writes out values as it encounters types that I know how to serialize.

However, I do recommend looking into WCF, not for building services, but for serialization. It shipped as part of the .NET 3.0 framework with a new assembly System.Runtime.Serilization and in general is very capable when dealing with serialization and data annotations.